# Correct way to model a collection of items in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

In the docs I see a lot of examples using index values as a part of the key name for a particular item --- but I don't understand how this is a consistent way to model your data.

For example let's say I have a list of articles:

```
https://gigablox.firebaseio.com/articles/
article1
article2
article3
```

When I'm ready to add `article4` I know I can use:

```
var length = Object.keys($scope.articles).length;
```

And using **AngularFire 0.5.0** I can save it with:

```
var name = 'article' + length + 1;
$scope.articles[name] = $scope.article;
$scope.articles.$save(name);
```

But what happens if I:

```
$scope.articles.$remove('article2');
```

And add another record using the same approach? *We're likely to create duplicate key names.*

To add a little complexity, let's add a single relationship and say that each *article* has `comments`.

What is the correct way to model this data in a Firebase collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `$add` and let Firebase automatically generate chronologically ordered lists for you.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://gigablox.firebaseio.com/articles/");
$scope.articles = $firebase(ref);

$scope.addArticle = function() {
  $scope.articles.$add($scope.article);
}

$scope.removeArticle = function(id) {
  $scope.articles.$remove(id);
}
```

Firebase automatically creates key names when you call `$add`. You can iterate over the key names using `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, article) in articles">
  <div ng-model="article"><a ng-click="removeArticle(key)">Remove</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well as disscussed above the tradeoff with `$add` and auto generated ID's come from article lookups right?. If I am searching for a specific article using a slug name as the object key its going to be much faster than pulling down the entire collection and searching for it.

Comment: This is where de-normalization comes in, I recommend creating an index that maps slugs to objects keys. You can retrieve an article in two fetches as opposed to searching (this approach is discussed in detail here: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html)

Comment: How do I access the unique ID generated for the record I just added?

Comment: `$add` will return a Firebase reference, you can get the name for that reference by calling `ref.name()`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** You should follow the suggestion from @Anant if you want an array-based collection.

However, for this specific scenario as outlined by @Dan Kanze, if you want to pull the key out of the URL (as would be done for a content management system, etc), you should generate your own keys unique to the content. For example, if you know that article names need to be unique, create a slug function that will:

1. Lowercase the article name
2. Replace spaces with underscores
3. etc..

If the article name changes, you would not delete the old entry. Instead, create a new entry in Firebase and use the old key to point to the new location for 301 redirects, etc.

Comment: I originally went with the second approach, but couldn't figure out how to update the key value of the object if the title updates. How would I update `title-of-old-artcle` to `title-of-new-article` without deleting the object? If I *have to* create a completely new object, how do I preserve the original index?

Comment: Unfortunately you would have to create a new object in that case. Firebase is all about being fast and light, so no changing keys after you've decided. Leave it something you know will stay fixed, or you should pick a key that is meaningless, like a hash.

Comment: But the tradeoff for using an array or the auto generated hash key are look-ups for specific articles correct? For example if a user landed on `example.com/articles/title-of-old-article` directly fetching the object where the title is also the key name is much faster than searching for the record whos title property matches that string right? Is it even possible to return a record whos title is equal to the value of that string or would you have to return the entire set of articles and then traverse over them to find the one you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, and actually I'll take your comment a bit further. Firebase doesn't (really) support searching. Even if/when it does, for that use-case you really want the slug in the URL to match the slug in Firebase. Otherwise it's bound to be drastically slower as you point out. If you're using this for URLs, you want them fixed anyway. So I'd generate the slug, and if the user changes the title, copy the data to a new Firebase object, but keep the old one. The old one can then maybe just be a placeholder with a location to the new article, which you can base your 301 redirects off of.

Comment: I don't recommend using array indexes in a distributed scenario as it's very easy for these to conflict and create "holes" in your list fairly easily. For this reason, Firebase provides a client-side way to generate automatic IDs that are guaranteed to be ordered (they are a hash of some random component + timestamp to prevent conflicts while remaining ordered).