# $on loaded fires once for new references AngularFire 0.5.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Let's say were using *pushState* to navigate routes:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

And there are two routes with two different controllers:

```
$stateProvider.state('one', {
  url:'/one',
  templateUrl:'one.html',
  controller: 'oneCtrl'
});

$stateProvider.state('two', {
  url:'/two',
  templateUrl:'two.html',
  controller: 'twoCtrl'
});
```

`oneCtrl` creates a new reference to the same resource as `twoCtrl`:

```
.controller('oneCtrl', ["$scope", "$firebase", function($scope, $firebase) {

  var oneRef = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/stuff");
  $scope.stuff = $firebase(oneRef);
  $scope.stuff.$on("loaded", function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
}])

.controller('twoCtrl', ["$scope", "$firebase", function($scope, $firebase) {

  var twoRef = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/stuff");
  $scope.stuff = $firebase(twoRef);
  $scope.stuff.$on("loaded", function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
}])
```

- If we navigate to `/one` the `$on("loaded")` event fires as expected - unique to the `oneRef`.
- If we then navigate from `/one` to `/two` the `$on("loaded")` event does not fire.

If a new ref was instantiated - `twoRef` - why doesn't the callback fire a **second time**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that locally cached data fires `value` events synchronously in Firebase.

On the first load, the server is contacted asynchronously by angularFire's [_getInitialValue](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/master/angularfire.js#L258) method. However, on the second load, since the value is already local, the [broadcast event](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/master/angularfire.js#L255) happens synchronously, and therefore before your $on('loaded'...) handler gets attached.

A couple thoughts come to mind: If the controllers are utilizing the same $firebase data, there should probably--in most common use cases--only be one. It should be moved to a service and shared accordingly.

Another workaround would be to store the loaded state in a service or in the $rootScope.

Ultimately, it should be [corrected in angularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/194) so that the loaded event triggers even if the 'value' is already loaded synchronously.

Comment: Thanks! - btw this was just a minimal example. There is a use case that I've run into where I need an ID from the value of the first collection in `controller1` to query the second collection in a `controller2`. Specifically - `/articles/list` (returns `articlesIndex` collection that maps `articles` collection generated IDs to *title slug key names*) and `/articles/edit/:id`. For example `my-seo-title:{article:'-JaX328-e32'}` - a pattern recommended to me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735728/correct-way-to-model-a-collection-of-items-in-firebase#comment-31095052